# Script to Compare TFS labels in a folder

Tags: powershell, tfs, msbuild

I have several branches in TFS (dev, test, stage) and when I merge changes into the test branch I want an automated script to find all the updated SQL files based on the labels and deploy them to the SQL database.

Currently I manually use compare in TFS source control explorer to get the files that are changed and use a custom powershell script to deploy to the database.

I am looking for a script that would copy the changed sql files to a repository so that my powershell will do the rest.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Nit